Text in Spinner Not Visible After Selection in Dark Mode
I'm a beginner in Android development, and I'm encountering an issue with a Spinner in my Android application. When I switch to dark mode, the text color of the selected item in the Spinner becomes invisible against the background. However, the dropdown list shows the text correctly when expanded. This issue does not occur in light mode; everything works perfectly there.
Here's a summary of my setup:
I'm using Material Components for my UI.
The theme is set to Theme.Material3.DayNight.NoActionBar which should adapt well to dark mode.
I have not manually set any specific colors for the Spinner; I'm relying on the default theme colors.
<Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinner"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:minHeight="48dp" />

What I Have Tried:
Verified that the app's theme is correctly set to adapt to dark mode.
Tested on multiple devices to confirm that it’s not device-specific.
What I Am Looking For:
I would appreciate any guidance on how to ensure that the selected text in the Spinner is visible in dark mode. Is there a property or theme adjustment that I might have missed?
here are some screenshot from my app:
here, text is not visible correctly
In the dropdown menu text is visible
